# How many arrangements of letters in ORIGINATING have ALL of the following properties?

Tags: combinatorics

How many arrangements of letters in ORIGINATING have ALL of the following properties:

(i) there are at least two letters between each I,

(ii) begins or ends with an I (does NOT begin AND end with an I), and

(iii) the consonants are in alphabetical order.

The answer is: $2 \times C(3+(8-5)-1,(8-5))C(8,6) \times 1 \times 2!$

Can someone explain to me where these numbers are coming from?
I know the $2$ in the beginning is for the two cases (begins with an I or ends with an I) both cases are the same.

There are $1$ A's, $3$ I's, and $1$ O's. The consonants are: $1$ R's, $2$ G's, $2$ N's and $1$ T's. The consonants in order are $GGNNRT$.

Comment: Please use \times or \cdot for multiplication.  They produce, respectively, $\times$ and $\cdot$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To describe one arrangement, you have to provide :

a) whether it begins or ends with I (2 possibilities)

b) the positions of the I's (for that I enumerated the 10 cases which is equal to $5 \choose 3$ but I don't understand the reason for this combinatorics)

c) the position of the 6 consonants among the 8 remaining non-I remaining letters : $8 \choose 6$

d) the order between a and o in the last 2 remaining positions : 2!

Comment: For part b), you can let $x_1, x_2, x_3$ be the number of letters in the gaps between the I's.  Then $x_1+x_2+x_3=8$ where $x_1,x_2\ge2$ and $x_3\ge1$ (if the word begins with I), so there are $\binom{5}{3}$ solutions.

Comment: Sorry, not clear for me... I understand until the conclusion. What set of three elements are you choosing among what set of 5 ?

Comment: If we let $y_1 = x_1 - 2$, $y_2 = x_2 - 2$, and $y_3 = x_3 - 1$, we obtain $y_1 + y_2 + y_3 = 3$.  We then need to choose where to place two addition signs in a row of three ones.  For instance, $+ 1 1 + 1$ corresponds to the solution $y_1 = 0$, $y_2 = 2$, $y_3 = 1$.  The number of ways we can do this is $\binom{5}{2}$ since we must choose which two of the five symbols (addition signs and ones) will be addition signs.

Comment: OK very clever !